# How to map a single touchscreen across multiple displays?

Tags: x11, xrandr, multi-monitor, xinput, touch-screen

I have a project that will have a single touchscreen spanning across multiple displays.  The displays are not butted against each other, there's some space between them, but the touch sensor spans that area too (that needs to be ignored).  I know how to use xinput to map a touch input to a specific display, but is there a way to map touch offsets from one sensor to different displays?  This needs to be a command-line solution.

I tried creating a single virtual display spanning the monitors and mapping the touch to that, but xinput doesn't support the virtual display as a target.

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 3
0: +*eDP-1 1024/300x600/200+0+0  eDP-1
1: +DP-1 1024/300x600/200+1024+0  DP-1
2: +HDMI-1 1920/508x1080/286+2048+0  HDMI-1
$ xrandr --setmonitor virtualGroup auto eDP-1,DP-1
output list eDP-1,DP-1
add monitor eDP-1
output name eDP-1
add monitor DP-1
output name DP-1
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
0: virtualGroup 2048/300x600/200+0+0  eDP-1 DP-1
1: +HDMI-1 1920/598x1080/336+2048+0  HDMI-1
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 0e8f:2517                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7200-77EAv1.000                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lenovo Optical USB Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
$ xinput --map-to-output 11 'virtualGroup'
Unable to find output 'virtualGroup'. Output may not be connected.
```

This will be on Linux 4.15.0-70-generic (Ubuntu 18.04) running OpenBox with LightDM.